# DW1000 with RP2040 (Not able to establish communication b/w two DW1000 module using RP2040)

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040, uwb

I have two DW1000 UWB modules, and I want to use them as an Anchor and TAG. I am currently using the Arduino DW1000 library. However, I encountered an error during SPI initialization related to mbed OS. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

I also attempted to port the Arduino DW1000 library to the pico C/C++ platform. Unfortunately, I only managed to obtain the Device ID, and I am struggling to establish communication between the two DW1000 modules. I kindly request your guidance in resolving this matter.

When I searched for a library for the DW1000 module, I found two options: one for the Arduino platform and another for the STM32. However, I have an RP2040 board, specifically a Raspberry Pico, and I want to establish communication between two DW1000 modules using this board.

I initially tried using the Arduino platform, and I was able to successfully run the "Basic Connectivity" example, which provided me with the device ID of the DW1000 module (0XDECA0130).
Next, I attempted to port the Arduino library to the RP2040 C/C++ platform. However, even after porting, I am still only able to obtain the device ID and not establish further communication.

It seems that the issue lies in the generation of interrupts. When I manually trigger an interrupt externally, the interrupt callback function works. However, the DW1000 module does not generate interrupts when transmitting or receiving data.

I am unsure about what I might be doing wrong in this process. Since interrupt generation is crucial for communication, I would appreciate guidance on how to proceed and successfully establish communication between the DW1000 modules using the RP2040 or Raspberry Pico.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunally I have never worked with DW1000 modules but over the last 2 years my colleque and I developed an Proof-of-Concept for a 3D Positioning system based on ESP32 and DWM3000 modules. Since we needed to port the Quorvo C-libaries to the ESP32 environment there might be some similarities to your application.

We are currently publishing a paper which shows the results we achieved.
Furthermore, you can have a look at the following [repository](https://github.com/krebsbstn/uwb-tracking) giving access to our full implementation, including source files, PCB designs and documentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).